# What does "s:" mean here?

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a string value into double type using parseDouble(). Parse double accepts a string that I am passing to it using getText(). But it doesn't work. Then I concatenated it with double-quotes. It's working now.  But I have a confusion here. Why does it not work without concatenation despite the fact that it accepts a string and getText() is, of course, getting a string. After writing the statement the compiler added "s:". I also wanna know what does this means here. I am using Android Studio 3.5.0.0

I have tried:

```
val1=Double.parseDouble(ioTxt.getText());
```

but this doesn't work.

The correct statement is:

```
val1 = Double.parseDouble(s: ioTxt.getText()+"");
```

ioTxt is a TextView. Val1 is a variable of type double. s: is something that compiler added and it is not a part of syntax and statement written above

The above statement also works well if write toString() instead of concatenation. It is:

```
val1 = Double.parseDouble(ioTxt.getText().toString());
```

but again I don't understand why does it require toString() to work well.

I expect to work it without concatenation of it with quotation marks or toString().

Comment: what do you type in `ioTxt`?

Comment: *"ioTxt is a TextView. Val1 is a variable of type double. s: is something that compiler added and it is not a part of syntax and statement written above"* Please don't describe your code, show your code. See [MCVE] for guidance.

Comment: The compiler doesn't modify your source code. You're probably looking at a argument name hint that Android studio, your IDE, displays inside the editor to let you know the name of the parameter of parseDouble(). It's not part of the source code, just like the source code is not colored, but is just pure text, that is displayed in color by the IDE.

Comment: And you need to call toString() because getText() returns a CharSequence, not a String, and parseDouble() expects a String, not a CharSequence. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText(), https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-. The javadoc is your best friend. Read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `android.widget.TextView.getText()` method is declared as returning a `CharSequence` rather than a `String`.  (See [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText()).)

The `CharSequence` interface is one of the declared interfaces of `String`.  (See [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html).)

The `Double.parseDouble` takes a `String` argument.  (See [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-).)

Therefore there is a type mismatch in this:

```
val1 = Double.parseDouble(ioTxt.getText());  // expects String
                                             // provided CharSequence
```

but this works:

```
val1 = Double.parseDouble(ioTxt.getText().toString());
```

because `toString()` is converting the `CharSequence` to a `String`.   And this is another way of doing the conversion:

```
val1 = Double.parseDouble(ioTxt.getText() + "");
```

---

Note however that this is not valid Java code:

```
val1 = Double.parseDouble(s: ioTxt.getText()+"");
```

You are *most likely* misinterpreting what your IDE is saying.

Answer (score 2):

> but again I don't understand why does it require toString() to work well.

[`Double.parseDouble()` takes an argument of type `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)).

The `getText()` method evidently returns something other than a `String` and therefore you need to convert.

Appending an empty string is a hacky way to force a `String` conversion (the `+` operator with one `String` argument implicitly calls `toString()` on the other argument).  Prefer an explicit `toString()` call.

The 's:' is simply the parameter name as used by `parseDouble()`, and is displayed by your IDE as a hint. It's not actually modifying your source code.

Answer (score -1):

[parseDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)) accepts String as parameter.

You are getting error as you are trying to pass a double instead of String.

For second question,
compiler never adds anything to your source files. The "s:" you see, is a way of IDE you are using, to show the parameter you are setting while calling the method.

Comment: He is not passing a `double`.